# Changing Display of Div not working correctly on iPad(8.0.1, Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On a button click event in jQuery I have code that shows a div(and it's contents) which were previously set to 'display:none;". It works fine on all other browsers but not Safari on the iPad.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <cfoutput>var cnt = #cnt#;</cfoutput>
    $('##add_#dialog_label#_b').click(function() {
        if (cnt < 10) {
            cnt++
            document.getElementById("#dialog_label#_dv_" + cnt).style.display = "";
        }
    });
});
```

I've also tried all the following 'show' functions:

```
$("###dialog_label#_dv_"+cnt).fadeIn(); 
$("###dialog_label#_dv_" + cnt).css('display','inline'); 
$("###dialog_label#_dv_" + cnt).show();
```

Everyone one of which work fine on all other browsers. Also the dozens of hash tags are Coldfusion evaluations. Another possibly important note is this is all taking place within a modal window.

Comment: Try it without the # in the ID. the # is a jQuery syntax, not javascript. Alternatively, could you say `$('#dialog_label#_dv_' + cnt).show();` (the syntax of the element still isn't right-- doesn't need two #. What does your element look like?

Comment: ColdFusion resolves all that so that when the JS/Jquery runs it looks like:
      '$(#pest_dv_" + cnt).show();'
I don't think it would target the object if I took out all the '#'s.

Comment: @Chad I guess the `#` as something to do with Coldfusion but then sounds like it should be e.g `$("##dialog_label#_dv_" + cnt).show();` But i'm not a Coldfusion user, only guessing

Comment: Have you tried: `document.getElementById("#dialog_label#_dv_" + cnt).style.display = "block";`?

Comment: In ColdFusion '##' evaluates to '#'. I've got the right number of hash's in there, just trust me.

Comment: @Wolff OKAY! That worked! ... Would you mind telling me why?

Comment: Because `.style.display = "";` isn't valid value so i guess Safari just ignore it. Other browsers could handle it as inherited property, really not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @Wolff here:

```
document.getElementById("#dialog_label#_dv_" + cnt).style.display = "block";
```

This worked just fine on Safari. The apparent reasoning being that when I chose not to set display to any value (other than an empty string) it ignored the command. I don't understand whythe newest version of Safari on the newest version of iOS was refusing to do these things using jQuery, but I'm happy with this solution!

UPDATE: Still not working on the clients iPad. I'm at a loss.